# Cannot convert [object Object] to (class)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to count the number of rows between two rows containing particular words in google sheets. But I am getting the following error:
Cannot convert [object Object] to (class). (line 41, file "Code")

I have written the following code on the google app script:

```js
function search(SPREADSHEET_ID, SHEET_NAME, word) {
    var locatedCells = [];
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
    var searchLocation = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();        
    //Loops to find the search term. 
        for (var j = 0, jLen = searchLocation.length; j < jLen; j++) {
            for (var k = 0, kLen = searchLocation.length; k < kLen; k++) {
                var find = word;
                if (find == searchLocation[j][k]) {
                    locatedCells.push({ 'found': (j + 1)});
                }
            }
        }
     //   Logger.log(locatedCells);
        return(locatedCells)
    }


 function footerlocation(){
  var SPREADSHEET_ID = "1nYBEuMMC4j1A4qryzKKq33PsTRH54ADyJLsEoTmbKh4"
  var SHEET_NAME = "Bedding"
  var word = "Footers"
  var footerlocation = search(SPREADSHEET_ID, SHEET_NAME, word)
  //Logger.log(footerlocation);
  return(footerlocation)
}


 function keywordlocation(){
  var SPREADSHEET_ID = "1nYBEuMMC4j1A4qryzKKq33PsTRH54ADyJLsEoTmbKh4"
  var SHEET_NAME = "Bedding"
  var word = "Keyword Page Redirects to Implement"
  var keywordlocation = search(SPREADSHEET_ID, SHEET_NAME, word)
  //Logger.log(keywordlocation);
  return(keywordlocation)
}

function count(){
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nYBEuMMC4j1A4qryzKKq33PsTRH54ADyJLsEoTmbKh4").getSheetByName("Bedding");
  var startrow=footerlocation()
  var endrow= keywordlocation()
  var range = sheet.getRange(startrow,1,endrow-startrow,1);
  var datas = range.getValues();
  var count = 0;
  for (data in datas) {
      for (cell in data) {
           //Logger.log(typeof cell) //{
            count++;
          //}
  }

 }
Logger.log(data)



}
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Welcome. Which one is line 41?

Comment: Its this one: var range = sheet.getRange(startrow,1,endrow-startrow,1);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution, change the count function to the following:

```
function count(){
  var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nYBEuMMC4j1A4qryzKKq33PsTRH54ADyJLsEoTmbKh4").getSheetByName("Bedding");
  var startrow=footerlocation()[0]['found']
  var endrow= keywordlocation()[0]['found']
  var range = sheet.getRange(startrow,1,endrow-startrow,1);
  var datas = range.getValues();
  var count = 0;
  for (data in datas) {
      for (cell in data) {
           //Logger.log(typeof cell) //{
            count++;
          //}
  }

 }
Logger.log(data)

}
```